# Show the last label

Tags: c#, label, mschart

I have a .net ms chart showing historical values of a stock with monthly labels

```
graph.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Months;
graph.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = System.Math.Truncate(1 + MonthsCount / 30d);
graph.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.IsEndLabelVisible = true;
```

Is it possible to display the last label without setting every single label ? 
Number of months and days in a month will always vary.

Comment: Are you asking a label on the axis or a label on the data point?

Comment: And you should update your question of what you have tried and what's the difference between what you want and what you get.

Comment: Labels are alway spaced out equally. You may need to take full control by switching to CustomLabels.